# Code first not running all the migrations

Tags: ef-code-first

I have this structure of migration of code first approach

[image]

I deleted the previous database and wants code first to create it again, but when I am doing `update-database` it is not running all the scripts and leaving first three migrations and because of it, it is failing because all the dependencies are not present

[image]

You see it is just picking up three migrations leaving the first three.

Earlier this used to work. What wrong might be going on? Somewhere it is still storing that the first three are already run while they are not since database itself doesn't exist and it is creating the database for the first time

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason.
I changed the namespace of last three and so it was picking up only those and not the first three. 
Just changed the namespace of first three also and it worked :)